# Read multiple values from a String with sscanf

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I want to read lines of data from a file. Everything i try doesn't work.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

"< x = 128 y = 480 img = img/A.png type = passable >"

Now i want to read 4 values from this string.

```
char img[256];
char ObjectType[256];
sscanf_s(lines[i].c_str(),"< x = %i y = %i img = %s type = %s >",&x,&y,img,ObjectType);
```

But everytime i get Memoryleaks.

Do you have an idea?

Edit:

I solved my problem with in my opionion unclean method. I used an istringstream:

```
            istringstream iss(lines[i]);
            iss >> temp >> temp >> temp >>
            x >> temp >> temp >>
            y >> temp >> temp >>
            img >> temp >> temp >> 
            ObjectType;
```

Comment: You can't modify the buffer given by `c_str()`. It returns a `const char *` for a reason.

Comment: @chris what does that mean? I only get a string so i have to use c_str()

Comment: First of all, if it's stored in constant memory, modifying it is undefined behaviour. The fact that it's marked `const` is a good indication. From C++11, you can safely use `&s[0]`, but you can't safely overwrite the final null or anything after.

Comment: @chris You mean something like this: sscanf_s(&lines[i][0],... ? This doesnt work. How would you solve it?

Comment: It's only guaranteed to work in C++11 and if the buffer can hold what you put into it. If you're not using C++11, you have to make a different buffer.

Comment: This code doesn't modify the buffer given by `c_str`. What memory leaks exactly do you have?

Comment: @AlexFarber Access Violation while writing at position. Somewhere in input.c

Comment: @DanielHuth Access Violation is not a memory leak, but an exception.  See my answer for a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

use the below line instead:

```
sscanf_s(lines[i].c_str(),"< x = %i y = %i img = %s type = %s >",&x,&y,img, _countof(img),ObjectType,_countof(ObjectType));
```

from [msdn documentation of sscanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

> a buffer size parameter is required when using the type field
>   characters c, C, s, S and [. The buffer size in characters must be
>   supplied as an additional parameter after each buffer which requires
>   it.

You were lacking the buffer size parameter, so it was trying to write an unknown number of bytes to `img`, after which is was trying to write what you want written to `ObjectType` to an undefined memory location, hence the exception you were encountering.